# Why is my data coming back in a random order, how do I make it right?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise

I'm making a pokedex in React, using PokeAPI.  The idea is to make them like Pokemon cards. Everything is working, but the data doesn't always come back in the right order (i.e. sometimes the back of say Charizards card, maps with Bulbasaurs front).  Shouldn't it always map right, since the second call goes is in a promise?

```
class Cardcontainer extends Component {
state= {
    pokemon: [],
    cardBack: []
}

componentDidMount() {
       fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon')
       .then(res => res.json())
       .then(res=> {
        this.setState({
            pokemon: [...res.results]
        })
       })
       .then(res=> {
           this.state.pokemon.forEach((poke)=> {
               fetch(poke.url)
               .then(res => res.json())
               .then(res => {
                   this.setState({
                       cardBack: [...this.state.cardBack, 
res]
                   })
               })
           })
       })

}
```

Comment: `.forEach()` starts all your `fetch(poke.url)` calls at once and runs them all in parallel. They order they finish in is indeterminate and depends upon the server they are going to.  You could use something like `Promise.all(this.state.pokemon.map(poke => {return fetch(...).then(res => res.json())})).then(results => { process all the results here in order})` to process them all in order.

Comment: add return to `this.setState()` to make sure the callback chain will process in order.

Comment: @boosted_duck return in setState throws an error.  jfriend answer worked.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that what you're asking for is to make the calls to `this.setState({cardBack: ...})` in the order that you issued the `fetch()` calls, then you can do that by collecting all the `fetch()` results in a `Promise.all()`.  That will run them all in parallel, but collect all the results in order.  Then, when they are all done, you can call `this.setState()` on each result in the order you issued the `fetch()` requests:

```
class Cardcontainer extends Component {
state= {
    pokemon: [],
    cardBack: []
}

componentDidMount() {
   fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon')
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(res=> {
        this.setState({pokemon: [...res.results]});
        return Promise.all(this.state.pokemon.map(poke=> {
           return fetch(poke.url).then(res => res.json())
        }));
   }).then(results => {
       // process all the results in order
       results.forEach(res => {
           this.setState({
               cardBack: [...this.state.cardBack, res]
           })
       })
   });
}
```

If this is not what you're asking for, then please edit your question to make the request more clear.